# Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'RangeInput'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-floppyforms

I'm trying to make a slider bar to allow users rate images in Django and I came across [Django-Floppyforms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

However I am having an issue when trying to work through the example [Slider Widget](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html)

As per the [PyPi Installation guidelines](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-floppyforms) I have installed it via pip in a virtual environment using the command `pip install -U django-floppyforms`. A `pip freeze` gives me

```
Django==1.6.2
django-floppyforms==1.2.0
```

I then added it to my `INSTALLED_APPS` in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...

    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'polls',
    'survey',
    'floppyforms',
)
```

I then created a floppyforms.py file at the same level as my models.py and views.py and coppied in the following

```
import floppyforms as forms


class Slider(forms.RangeInput):
    min = 5
    max = 20
    step = 5
    template_name = 'slider.html'

    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/jquery.min.js',
            'js/jquery-ui.min.js',
        )
        css = {
            'all': (
                'css/jquery-ui.css',
            )
        }


class SlideForm(forms.Form):
    num = forms.IntegerField(widget=Slider)

    def clean_num(self):
        num = self.cleaned_data['num']
        if not 5 <= num <= 20:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a value between 5 and 20")

        if not num % 5 == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a multiple of 5")
        return num
```

However as soon as I do this my existing application stops working and gives me the error

```
Exception Value:    'module' object has no attribute 'RangeInput'
```

Any ideas? I have googled the error but cant seem to get much on it. I'm running Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you named your file `floppyforms.py` which is the same name as the module.

Rename your file to `forms.py` which is the normal practice in django for forms.

Comment: Done. The above floppyforms.py was renamed forms.py. However I am still getting the same error. NOTE: The error appears when I refresh the existing working application.

Comment: You probably still have a floppyforms.pyc file, which you should delete.

Comment: Thanks a million. I never even considered this. For the record the floppyforms.pyc was in the same location but not visible in the Eclipse package explorer